# Create tables in word for each row in excel sheet

Tags: excel, ms-word, export

I'm creating a word report and all my data is on an excel sheet.
The sheet is like this:

```
ID Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4
1  blah  blah  blah  blah
2  blah  blah  blah  blah
3  blah  blah  blah  blah
```

And what I want is in the word document, to have one table for each line of the worksheet like this:

```
*-------*----*
|ID     |1   |
|Name1: |blah|
|Name2: |blah|
|Name3: |blah|
|Name4: |blah|
*-------*----*

*-------*----*
|ID     |2   |
|Name1: |blah|
|Name2: |blah|
|Name3: |blah|
|Name4: |blah|
*-------*----*

etc
```

I think that this should be pretty straight forward, but unfortunatelly I've never done something like that before.

Any ideas/pointers on how ti can be done are welcome!

Comment: As far as I know this is not straight forward at all. You could write a VB script to do this but it will take some time. Hints as to how to do this are (for example) here: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=14955

Answer (score 1):

The following code can help you. While using the code make sure of the following

1. The code below needs data to be in Sheet1.
2. The code works by copying data in Sheet1 to Sheet 2 so make sure that you don't have any important data in Sheet2

   ```
   Sub CopyRowToRC()
   Sheet2.Range("A:B").Clear
   i = 1
   j = 2
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With Sheet1
   LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With
   For i = 1 To LastRow

   With Sheet2
   LastRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   If i > 1 Then
   LastRows = LastRows + 2
   End If
   End With

   If j <= LastRow Then
   Sheet1.Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
   Sheet2.Range("A" & LastRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
   Sheet1.Rows(j).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy
   Sheet2.Range("B" & LastRows).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=True
   j = j + 1
   End If
   Next
   Sheet2.Activate
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   WordUp
   End Sub


   Sub WordUp()
   On Error Resume Next
   Dim WdObj As Object, fname As String
   fname = "File Name"
   Set WdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   WdObj.Visible = True

   With Sheet2
   LastRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   End With

   Sheet2.Range("A1:B" & LastRows).Copy

   WdObj.documents.Add
   WdObj.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
   With WdObj
       .ActiveDocument.Close
       .Quit
   End With
   Set WdObj = Nothing
   Sheet2.Range("A:B").Clear
   Sheet1.Activate
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   ```